# React Native scrollview infinitely rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I'm new to react native and I'm creating a to do list app. the component I wrote keeps infinitely re-rendering when I initialize Todos state to something that isn't an empty array. This results to an error where react stops it. I have no idea what is causing the infinite loop as I haven't included any recursion or explicit loops. I added a few console.log()'s everywhere and found that deleteTodo and toggleTodo keep getting called automatically until the application crashes.

When Todos state is initialized to an empty array I get an error saying that getTodos.map is not a function.

The component is only expected to re-render whenever the state is updated to either modify , add or delete a task.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { State, ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
/* All required imports are correctly added */

let id = 0
function TaskRow(props) {
    return (
        <View>
            {/* empty button acting as checkbox */}
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text />
            </TouchableHighlight>
            {/* main text area, displays task and all details + tags*/}
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.toggle(props.key)}>
                <Text>{props.task}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            {/* delete button */}
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.delete(props.key)}>
                <Text>Delete</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
}

export default function TodoList() {
    const [
        getTodos,
        setTodos,
    ] = useState([
        { key: id, task: 'this is a task', checked: false },
    ])

    const addTodo = (taskInput = 'sample') => {
        id++
        setTodos(getTodos.push({ key: id, task: 'task', checked: false }))
    }

    const deleteTodo = (deleteID) => {
        setTodos(getTodos.filter((match) => match.key !== deleteID))
    }

    const toggleTodo = (toggleID) => {
        setTodos(
            getTodos.map((match) => {
                if (match.key == toggleID) return { key: match.key, task: match.task, checked: !match.checked }
            }),
        )
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={addTodo}>
                <Text>Add task</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <ScrollView>
                {getTodos.map((task) => (
                    <TaskRow
                        key={task.key}
                        task={task.task}
                        delete={deleteTodo}
                        toggle={toggleTodo}
                    />
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: problem is the props for the `onPress` e.g. `onPress={props.toggle(props.key)}` - you are calling the functions as opposed to passing a function in so change those to `onPress={() => props.toggle(props.key)}` and it will stop looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your `TaskRow` component, on each render you are actually calling the functions instead of declaring an handler for events. Please chenge these two lines in this way:

```
// ...
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.toggle(props.key)}>
// ...
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.delete(props.key)}>
```

Another problem is this:

```
setTodos(getTodos.push({ key: id, task: 'task', checked: false }))
```

the `.push()` does not return the array so you should do something like:

```
setTodos([...getTodos, { key: id, task: 'task', checked: false }])
```

Comment: That did fix the infinite loop error but I still get the error saying getTodos.map is not a function even though I initialized it as an array.